# How to get this data with AJAX from JSON?

Tags: json, ajax, get

I was using this code below to get the title/artist data from an old-station (https://stream.mydnic.be/status-json.xsl) with ajax:

```
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: host + '/status-json.xsl',
        success: function(data) {
            artist = data.icestats.source.artist;
            title = artist + ' - ' + data.icestats.source.title;
            document.title = title;
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(worker, 3000);
        }
    });
```

Now I changed the station and the new one use another JSON file that looks a little different:

```
"id": "station_name",
"songs":[
{
"title": "Water Silence",
"artist": "Solar Fields",
"album": "Fahrenheit Project Part Five",
"albumart": "",
"date": "1569618168"
},
```

The problem is that now, I get '*undefined*' on **Title** and **artist** with the first Ajax Code.

So, I would like to ask if someone knows what I need to change on the first ajax code to work with the new JSON file and get the title/artist data correctly.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: indenting your JSON will help you to see the pieces.  You have a `songs` array, and the object at `songs[0]` has a bunch of properties, so `data.songs[0].title`, `data.songs[0].artist`, etc. should give you data (for the first song, at least).

Comment: That worked!!! thank you very much Clailes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get an attribute from an object when it is a list of objects, what you have to do is iterate the array or get the result by index.

Like this:

```
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: host + '/status-json.xsl',
        success: function(data) {
            //In this example you getting element by index
            artist = data.songs[0].artist;
            title = data.songs[0].title;
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(worker, 3000);
        }
    });
```